# Calculate unknown variable when surface area is given. (Calculus)

Tags: calculus

I hope I could get some help with the following calculus problem. I literally have no idea how to tackle this.

---

Here it is:

### For every value of p the following function is given:

$$f_{p} (x) = p(x^2-1)$$

Also:

$$V_{p}$$

### is the area contained by:

$$f_{p} \,\,\,and\,\,\,\, f_{1}$$

Here's the problem I need to solve:

### Calculate p *exactly* when surface area Vp equals 4 is given.

---

No idea how to tackle this because no lower limit or upper limit is given. I haven't seen this before using an indefinite integral.

Your help is very much appreciated,
Bowser

*Calculate ***exactly*** meaning without use of a calculator.

Comment: Do you know how integrals are connected to surface area?

Comment: I wonder whether the asker is misusing the word "surface area" whereas he actually wants "area". Both $\;f_p,\,f_1\;$ are one variable functions, so we have a two dimensional domain for which its area can, perhaps, be calculated. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes you calculate surface area with: F(b) - F(a). Upper limit minus lower limit. But I have no idea how to solve this because I have no upper or lower limit. First time I've seen this kind of problem.

Comment: Sorry for surface area, I had to translate it from dutch to english. Let me edit.

Comment: What kind of number is $\;p\;$ ? A natural one or a real one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate explicitly the intersection of the curves $y = p(x^2-1)$ and $y = (x^2-1)$ for all values of $p$ and you get $x_1=-1$ and $x_2=1$.

Then you can calculate the area between the two curves to get the value of p solving (if $p \le 1$):

$$4 = \int_{-1}^1 (p(x^2 -1) - (x^2 -1) )dx = \int_{-1}^1 (p-1)(x^2 -1)  dx $$

If $p \ge 1$ you have to change the sign of the integral because then $(x^2-1) \ge p(x^2 -1 )$ in the interval where you want to integrate.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and see if I can solve it this way. The understanding will come later.

Comment: @Bowser You're welcome. Try making a drawing of both $f_p$ and $f_1$ to understand the meaning of the integral that you have to solve.

Comment: This solution assumes $\;f_p\ge f_1\iff (p-1)(x^2-1)\ge0\iff p\le1\;$, since on $\;[-1,1]\;$ we have $\;x^2-1\le 0\;$  . Why is this so?

Comment: @Joanpemo Sure, I didn't realize. If $p \ge 1$ you just have to reverse the sign of the integral. I will edit to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: One more question for @A.A. how does one draw $$f_{p}$$?

Comment: @Bowser You can't do it. But you can draw it schematically for $p>1$ and $p<1$, this is what I was referring to. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Oh yes, I see thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

$$f_1=x^2-1\;,\;\;f_p=p(x^2-1)$$

The intersection of both functions above:

$$x^2-1=p(x^2-1)\iff(p-1)(x^2-1)=0\iff x=\pm1$$

and these are your integration bounds. Also

$$f_p\ge f_1\iff(p-1)(x^2-1)\ge0\iff p-1\le 0\;,\;\;\text{since}\;\forall x\in[-1,1],\;\;x^2-1\le 0 $$

so if $\;p\ge1\;$ , then always $\;f_1\ge f_p\;$ , and then

$$4=V_p=\int_{-1}^1\left[(x^2-1)-p(x^2-1)\right]dx=2(1-p)\int_0^1(x^2-1)dx=$$

$$=2(1-p)\left(\frac13-1\right)=\frac43(p-1)\implies p=4$$

If $\;p\le1\;$ you have to reverse the inequalities above (Warning: in this case the solution IS NOT $\;-4\;$. Check it)

Answer (score 2):

The area between $f_1$ and $f_p$ is 
\begin{align}
&\int_{-1}^1|f_1(x)-f_p(x)|d x\\
&=\int_{-1}^1|(1-p)(x^2-1)|d x\\
&=|1-p|\int_{-1}^1( 1-x^2) d x \\
&=\frac43 |1-p| \\
&=4
\end{align}
thus, $p=4\text{ or }p=-2$